# Number of ways to represent a number as a sum of K numbers in subset S

Tags: polynomials, combinations

Let the set $S = \{ 1 , 2 , 4 , 5 , 10\}$

Now I want to find the number of ways to represent $x$ as sum of $k$ numbers of the set $S$ (a number can be included any number of times).

If $x = 10$ and $k = 3$

Then the answer should be $2$ from $(5,4,1) ,\, (4,4,2)$. The order of the numbers doesn't matter ie. $(4,4,2)$ and $(4,2,4)$ count as one.

I did some research and found that the set can be represented as a polynomial $x^1+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^{10}$and after raising the polynomial to the power $k$ the coefficients of the product polynomial gives the answer.

But the answer includes $(4,4,2)$ and $(4,2,4)$ as unique terms which I don't want.

Is there any way to make $(4,4,2)$ and $(4,2,4)$ count as the same term ?

Comment: If you have *Mathematica*, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html do the work. But I don't know how it work internally.

Comment: @user202729 Ah, I am constantly discovering new things in Mathematica. So IntegerPartitions[12, {3}, {1, 2, 4, 5, 10}] returns {{10, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 2}, {4, 4, 4}}. Neat.

Comment: @user202729 thanks, but i really need to know the working .